# How to trigger a modal from a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have the following 2 radio buttons within a jquery modal

```js
function onNo() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioYes" value="true" id="radioYes" class="radioYes" checked="checked" onclick="onYes()" /><br />
    <span>Yes</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioNo" value="true" id="radioNo" class="radioNo" checked="checked" onclick="onNo()" /><br />
    <span>Yes</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-I'm calling the function **onYes()** and **onNo()** from these radio buttons.

When clicked on either of these radio buttons, I want to open another modal that asks for confirmation with OK and Cancel buttons.
However, when I click on Cancel or OK for one of the modals both the modals close. How can I prevent both the modals from closing at the same time?.

I understand that I can use the confirm modal, but I want to style it to look different with a modal title, body and footer.

Once again please pardon, if I've used the wrong technical terminologies as I am not a programmer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have created snippet for you now you edit it and create [mre] of your problem. When we see problem in action, we will be able to help.